# Adding lineargradientbrush inside graphicspath in c#

Tags: c#

hello how to fill lineargradientbrush on the graphicspath..
i have this code and solidbrush can only fill it.. i dont know how to fill it with lineargradientbrush.. any help please..

i have this code..

```
class KamoteButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        int width = this.Width-1;
        int height = this.Height-1;
        Color gradColor_a = Color.FromArgb(162, 177, 183);
        Color gradColor_b = Color.FromArgb(104, 111, 114);
        int radius = this.Width / 8;


        Graphics gFx = pevent.Graphics;
        gFx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddArc(0, 0, radius, radius, 180, 90);
        gp.AddLine(width / 8, 0, width - width / 8, 0);
        gp.AddArc(width - radius, 0, radius, radius, 270, 90);
        gp.AddLine(width, width / 8, width, height - width / 8);
        gp.AddArc(width - radius, height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
        gp.AddLine(width - width / 8, height, width / 8, height);
        gp.AddArc(0, height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
        gp.AddLine(0, height - width / 8, 0, width / 8);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);

        LinearGradientBrush lbg = new LinearGradientBrush(gp, gradColor_a, gradColor_b, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);

        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        gFx.FillPath(lbg, gp);
        this.Region = new Region(gp);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens, what doesn't and what did you expect? The SolidBrush is never used.

Comment: yep.. the solid brush is right there just to test that only solidbrush is working to fill the graphicspath.. im just asking for idea on how to use lineargradientbrush to fill the graphicspath.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to create the GradientBrushh won't compile:

```
 LinearGradientBrush lbg = new LinearGradientBrush(gp, 
    gradColor_a, gradColor_b, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
```

There is no constructor with a Path as parameter. Replace it with 2 points or 1 Rect

Comment: thanks sir.. im using this..   LinearGradientBrush lbg = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(this.Height, this.Height), gradColor_a, gradColor_b);